# How do I decompress .bgz files?

Tags: gunzip, unzip

Is there any software that will decompress a file named nnnnn.tsv.bgz on a PC running Windows 10?
The usual R commands will not do it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's [a "block gzipped" file](https://www.biostars.org/p/293729/) and should be viewable with anything that knows gzip files (tar, gzip, etc). Winzip/7zip might just need it's extension changed to .gz (windows is funny that way).

Or [Install the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and use linux tools, like `tar`, `gzip`, `file`, `bgzip` (provided in the `tabix` package in Debian & probably others)...

- More info here:
  https://blastedbio.blogspot.com/2011/11/bgzf-blocked-bigger-better-gzip.html

---

Or it could be a [Blood Frontier game Map File](https://fileinfo.com/extension/bgz), so use the game.

Answer (score 1):

That file extension sounds suspicious.  What i would do is check the first hex values of the file in a hex viewer to see really what kind of file it was.  How is it encoded or is it an archive, who knows. But, the first hex values in a file will usually not lie and say what they are--these are the "magic bytes"

First is a well-used resource showing common file types and their hex values.

[gary kessler list](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)

Lastly is an easy place to just upload it and have it checked

[file type checker](http://checkfiletype.com/)

Comment: Or, rather, just use the `file` command which will do this for you.

Comment: True, but not available on a PC running windows 10 as OP mentioned.

Comment: What about the linux/ubuntu subsystem for windows? It should even have gzip & tar, might have no problem with it

Comment: Fair points, but should be stated up-front as a requirement along with the instructions in the helpful tip.  Also no guarantee this isnt just ascii text and not an archive so a file type check first i think is reasonable and quick.

Comment: Point, I'd somehow missed that. It [is available](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) for Windows but whether that's preferred over the online checker would depend on file size and privacy concerns (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Try the freeware 7-zip:
https://www.7-zip.org/

It can decompress archive of many known file types.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) with command below to unzip:

```
gunzip -c nnnnn.tsv.bgz > nnnnn.tsv
```

Or:

```
gzcat nnnnn.tsv.bgz > nnnnn.tsv
```

This answer is come from [github link](https://github.com/macarthur-lab/gnomad_browser/issues/65).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).